# Angular.js: two-way binding inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an Angular application.

I want to generate a form with an arbitrary number of text input fields with two-way bindings for **every individual input field**. No buttons, no watchers. `ng-model` is not working correctly because of the scoping (if I'm not mistaken). The input fields are generated from an array with ng-repeat like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <label>{{item.name}}</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.default}}" ng-model="{{item.value}}"> <!-- this input should be bound -->
 </div>
```

I just want a simple binding to update the `items` array in the controller on changes in the input.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You only need angular braces {{var}} if you're writing it out to the page. When using it in repeats or models or filters, you don't need the braces. Note you're already doing this in the ng-repeat, you didn't do "item in {{items}}".

Comment: Thank you for the advice James! I think I understood Angular a little bit better (I'm still new to  it though :) )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just change input tag so it reads:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{item.default}}" ng-model="item.value">
```

Notice `ng-model` without curly braces.

Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/CLdem9yIw2Sk1U52Iajl?p=preview

Comment: this plnkr does not work. I clearly see the mustache value {{item.name}} is not getting updated.